# Check for a file before the program loads

Tags: java, events, awt

The idea is to create a home screen that loads required information out from a text file. The application looks for the file, and if it is not found it asks for the file path.

so far i have this code

```
    BufferedReader br;

    try{
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(principal));
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        while(!principal.contains(".INICIO")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Not a valid file paht", "error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            JFileChooser archivo = new JFileChooser("Seleccione el archivo principal");
            principal = archivo.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        }
    }
```

After that i want the program to try again with the new file path. I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
   while(condition){
       try{
           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(principal));
       }catch(Exception e){
           //some code here
       }
   }
```

but i dont know what the "condition" is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use `File#exists`?

Comment: not sure about that, if the file does not exist it automaitcally throws an exception. And if the file does Exist it wouldn't even try to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to a number of work flows.  If you're only interested in know if the file that the user has selected exists you could do something like...

```
JFileChooser archivo = new JFileChooser("Seleccione el archivo principal");
int action = archivo.showOpenDialog(null);
File principal = archivo.getSelectedFile();
while (action != JFileChooser.CACNEL_OPTION && !principal.exists()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Not a valid file paht", "error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    action = archivo.showOpenDialog(null);
    principal = archivo.getSelectedFile();
}

if (!action == CACNEL_OPTION) {
    // File reference should now be valid, open and read away...
}
```

Now, if you also want to know if the file was valid, you would need to read it.  About this point, I would create a method that could prompt the user for a `File` and which could return `null` if they selected <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, this way you can better control the flow...

Comment: That seems to do it. Thank you.